# How do I configure Mozilla Thunderbrid 3.1

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I have Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1 on Windows XP.

I need to configure Thunderbird to do the following:

- I want to move Thunderbird into the Notification Area.
- Whenever I get mail i should get a notification and I want to check mail every one minute.
- I want to check a gmail account every one minute.

I have ready added some plugins. Please let me know how I can do the above.

Comment: If you use IMAP, you don't even need to check "every 1 min" -- Thunderbird will notify you immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird will notify you when there is new mail, so you don't need to do anything to configure that

To get thunderbird in the notification area see:

> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Minimize_to_system_tray_%28Thunderbird%29

To change the related to the frequency of checking the server for new mail:

Open thunderbird, go to Tools/Account Settings/Server Settings and enter the value you wish.

[image]